# No getting parameter from key storage in a ResourceModelSource plugin

Tags: rundeck

I'm creating a simple ResourceModelSource plugin written in Python3 and I'm stuck with a config parameter. The question is I want to get the login password from key storage and I've created this config:

```
- type: String
   name: cmdb_password
   title: CMDB login password
   description: Password to login to CMDB API.
   scope: InstanceOnly
   required: false
   default: keys/mordor_pass
   renderingOptions:
   selectionAccessor: STORAGE_PATH
   valueConversion: PRIVATE_DATA_CONTEXT
   instance-scope-node-attribute: cmdb_password
   groupName: CMDB Login
```

The problem is that when the Python scripts runs it gets from enviromental variables "keys/mordor_pass" instead of the real password. All the other parameters are obtained well except this one. In the script I've this:

```
cmdb_password = os.getenv('RD_CONFIG_CMDB_PASSWORD')
```

I've been using as a reference this URL https://github.com/rundeck/guitars-demo/blob/master/plugins/mtl-exec-plugin/mtl-exec-plugin/plugin.yaml and I cannot understand where the problem could be. Could someone give me some light on this, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Checking [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6775) thread (opened by you) and [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/pull/6666) (original Pull request), it seems something that needs some fix to work properly, probably in the next release.

Comment: I think the same. I'm just waiting if any of the developers can work in the issue to collaborate. I would like to solve by myself but I don't have the necessary programming skills.

Comment: It seems assigned to a dev member :-)